# Why does't switching classes in react work?

Tags: reactjs

As you can tell, by `changing(onChange)` the `<ReactStars>` component, the recipe gets rated BUT I want the `<ReactStars>` component disappear after `onChange` is triggered so I created parse `useState` which is at first set to True with corresponding `CSSclass` and later setting in `onChange` to false and star 2 class. From some reason the component doesn't disappear though. Any idea?

**Details.js**

```js
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Details.css';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Image from './vitaminDfood-1132105308-770x553.jpg';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactStars from 'react-rating-stars-component';
import { RecipeContext } from './RecipeContext';
import { useContext, useRef } from 'react';

function Details() {
  const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);
  const { recipeId } = useParams();
  const initialRatings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`rating-${recipeId}`) || '[]');
  const { recipes, setRecipes } = useContext(RecipeContext);
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(initialRatings);
  const [parse, setParse] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`https://cookbook.ack.ee/api/v1/recipes/${recipeId}`).then((res) => setDetails(res.data));
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(`rating-${recipeId}`, JSON.stringify(rating));
  }, [rating, recipeId]);

  const ratingChanged = (newRating) => {
    setParse(false);
    var rate = {
      score: newRating,
    };
    setRating(newRating);
    axios.post(`https://cookbook.ack.ee/api/v1/recipes/${recipeId}/ratings`, rate).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      setRecipes(recipes);
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="details">
        <div className="food-photo">
          <img src={Image} alt="" />
          <Link to="/">
            {' '}
            <i className="fas fa-arrow-left arrow"></i>
          </Link>
          <h1>{details.name}</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="star-line">
          {new Array(rating).fill(null).map(() => (
            <i className="fas fa-star stari" />
          ))}

          <p className="duration">
            <i className="far fa-clock"></i>
            {details.duration}
            <span>min.</span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <p className="info">{details.info}</p>
        <h1 className="ingredience">Ingredience</h1>

        <div className="ing">{details.ingredients}</div>

        <h1 className="ingredience">Příprava</h1>
        <p className="description">{details.description}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="stars">
        <ReactStars classNames={parse ? 'star' : 'star2'} size={48} onChange={ratingChanged} count={5} value={1} edit />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Details;
```

**Details.css**

```css
.star {
  margin-right: 20%;
  margin-left: 23%;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.5 ease-out;
}
.star2 {
  margin-right: 20%;
  margin-left: 23%;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.5 ease-out;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: `classNames` should be `className` ?

Comment: no actually for this library it works like this

Comment: Is `ratingChanged` really called on a rating change?

Comment: yep,it does,tried it now